# autoscrolling for UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview

I used the setContentOffset method to scroll to a particular point automatically without user interaction.

```
[menuScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(600.0,0) animated:YES]
```

but when i try to call the same method in a looping fashion inorder to slow down the speed of scrolling the scrolling never happens

```
for (int i = 1; i<=30; i++) {
        [menuScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(600.0-i*10,0.0) animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"%f",600.0-i*10);        
    }
```

During the above piece of code the scrolling of UIScrollview happens only once (1st iteration( and it does not scroll for remaining 29 interations. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that when it's in a loop like this, the UI won't be updated.

Try using an NSTimer instead of putting it in a tight loop like this.

```
scrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(scrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) scrollView {
    CGFloat currentOffset = menuScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat newOffset = currentOffset - 10;
    [menuScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newOffset,0.0) animated:YES];
}
```

Note: this is from the top of my head, so I don't guarantee that it will work.

Comment: thanks it worked. But is there any other way to move to make the scroll similar to marquee in HTML ?. this one is slow but i can feel that moving is not in a consistent speed. I tried this by decreasing the time interval but it is not looking fine, it is looking like a kind of shaking in both the direction. How to fix this up ? or is ther any other way to solve the marquee problem ?

Comment: I've decreased the time interval all the way down to .01 seconds; this produces smooth scrolling on an iPad 3. If you tried this on a 2010 device it might not have had the processing power to do that smoothly. Another option is to set the content offset to the end of the content view, inside of an animation block. This produced very smooth scrolling for me. However, with this method it's not possible to get the current scroll position as the animation runs, because the scroll position is really set to the end position when you set it, despite what you see on screen during the animation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is the code that automatically scroll UIScrollView with marquee effect:-

```
    ![CGFloat cx1;
    int h=0;
    int z=0;
    int x=1;
    bool isdragging=false;


- (void)setupHorizontalScrollView : (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if (arrTopFive.count == 0) {
        return;
    }

    for(UIView *subview in \[scrollView subviews\]) {
        \[subview removeFromSuperview\];
    }

    scrollView.delegate = self;

    \[scrollView setBackgroundColor:\[UIColor clearColor\]\];
    \[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO\];

//    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;




    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<arrTopFive.count;i++)
    {

        clsShows *c=\[arrTopFive objectAtIndex:i\];

        UIImageView *imageView = \[\[UIImageView alloc\] init\];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = \[\[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc\] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tvShowTopFiveClicked:)\];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        \[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture\];
        imageView.tag=i;

        \[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:\[NSURL URLWithString:c.imageurl\] placeholderImage:\[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_placeholder.jpg"\]\];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = 250;
        rect.size.width = 500;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;

        imageView.frame = rect;

        \[scrollView addSubview:imageView\];

        cx += imageView.frame.size.width+5;

    }

    \[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, \[scrollView bounds\].size.height)\];
    cx1=cx-\[scrollView bounds\].size.width;


    \[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES\];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.dragging) {
        isdragging=true;
        h=ceil((float)scrollView.contentOffset.x / 5) * 5;
        z=ceil((float)scrollView.contentOffset.x / 5) * 5;
        if (h<0) {
            h=0;
            z=0;

        }
        else if (h>cx1){
            h=cx1;
            z=cx1;
        }

        \[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startScroller) object:nil\];
        \[self performSelector:@selector(startScroller) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0\];

    }
}
-(void) startScroller{
    if (isdragging == true) {
        isdragging=false;
    }
}

- (void) onTimer {

    if (isdragging) {
        return;
    }

    if (h > cx1) {

        if (x <= 5){
            \[headerView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(z, 0) animated:YES\];
            x++;
            z--;
            return;
        }

        if (z <= 5){
            h=0;
        }
        z-=5;

        \[headerView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(z, 0) animated:YES\];
    }
    else{
        x=1;
        if (z<=5) {
            \[headerView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(h, 0) animated:YES\];
            z+=1;
        }
        else{
            h +=  5;
            z=h;
            \[headerView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(h, 0) animated:YES\];
        }

    }
}][1]
```